# Meaning of XCode clang error "not found in architecture i386"

Tags: xcode, clang

I'm not sure what these errors mean or what to do about them. I moved a folder and some files around in Finder, and then added them back to my project.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IASKSettingsReader", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IASKAppSettingsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IASKSettingsStoreUserDefaults", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IASKAppSettingsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IASKSpecifierValuesViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IASKAppSettingsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IASKPSTitleValueSpecifierViewCell", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in IASKAppSettingsViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is followed by these error messages (which I can't copy as text)

[image]

I had just compiled successfully before the files were moved and added.

Comment: Yes. I had to wait for the timer to accept. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class IASKSettingsReader/IASKSettingsStoreUserDefaults/... is not being linked. Please check that you have it included on your Xcode project and in the Build Phases of your project under Compile Sources, if not add them.

Comment: Thanks. I was thrown by the i386 reference. I wish I could sort the compile source list. It's getting so long, I can't see everything that's in it.