# Apple Mach-O linker Error for libz.1.dylib framwork

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Iam developing one application.In that i am using libz.1.dylib framework.And this application will be working fine in simulator.When i try to archive this application i got a error like Apple Mach-O linker error.And show the error like

```
/Users/wifin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StudyApp-fhamcsbyepwhdebjbmkfyfbroacl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/IpadExStudyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/StudyApp.app/StudyApp normal armv7
cd /Users/wifin/Desktop/K.V.Naresh/SmartSvn/27-04-2012
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 3.0
setenv PATH "/Users/wifin/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/wifin/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Users/wifin/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Users/wifin/Desktop/software/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -L/Users/wifin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StudyApp-fhamcsbyepwhdebjbmkfyfbroacl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/IpadExStudyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/wifin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StudyApp-fhamcsbyepwhdebjbmkfyfbroacl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/IpadExStudyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/wifin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StudyApp-fhamcsbyepwhdebjbmkfyfbroacl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/IpadExStudyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/StudyApp.build/Release-iphoneos/StudyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/StudyApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -miphoneos-version-min=3.0 -lz -lsqlite3.0 -framework AVFoundation -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/wifin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StudyApp-fhamcsbyepwhdebjbmkfyfbroacl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/IpadExStudyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/StudyApp.app/StudyApp
```

ld: library not found for -lz
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

So please tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: Have you checked for this library in  Build Phases tab?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Check that each module and lib you expect to be in the build are actually in the build

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551503/meaning-of-xcode-clang-error-not-found-in-architecture-i386) SO answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427396/whats-the-correct-way-to-configure-xcode-4-workspaces-to-build-dependencies-whe) answer also for more clang errors and what to try.

You should still link against libz as a matter of course:

Instead of linking against libz.1.dylib you need to link against libz.dylib

Remove the entry for libz.1.dylib from your linker settings and add libz.dylib manually

[image]

Comment: Then it's not to do with libz in and of itself.

Comment: So what is the problem.iam using xcode 4.3.2 and ios 5.I installed xcode in separate folder.Is it problem for that one.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I removed libz.1.2.3.dylib & libz.1.2.5.dylib but kept libz.dylib. For the first time in ages, I have an app with no warnings. Thanks

Comment: Even I'm getting the same error.Does anyone has solved the problem