# Getting error while archiving

Tags: ios, iphone

I have included libz.dylib in my project.When running on simulator it doesnt gives error.But when archiving its giving me error.

I'm getting below mentioned error

```
ld: library not found for -lz clang: error: linker command failed
with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I searched a lot but could not found the solution.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497103/apple-mach-o-linker-error-for-libz-1-dylib-framwork

Comment: I have gone through it but still I am getting same error